Manhwa where the main character is taken from her kingdom
The main character is a young child. The duke conquered her kingdom and defeated it. She was treated horribly by her family .. the duke was about to kill her but I think he took her back to the imperial palace to see what the emperor had to say. The emperor ordered him to kill her once she become of age, or at least is old enough (since she's too small and weak). She also has magical powers (or something like that) which allows her to communicate with small deities like fairies inside the palace. The deities or fairies protect the castle.

This is Baby Prisoner of the Winter Castle. It is licensed by Tapas.

The last survivor of the Grezekaiah royal family is biding her time as a prisoner waiting to die… too bad everyone finds her absolutely adorable. When Clarisse became the youngest prisoner of Duke Maximilian Sheridan, she never expected her captors to be the family she’d always wished for. With an execution date set for her eighteenth birthday, will her emerging powers, bubbly personality, and cute face save her from her fate?

The story opens with the execution of the protagonist's family, the royal family of a conquered nation. The Duke performing the executions in front of the emperor insists that the protagonist cannot be executed as she is still a child.

As he won't kill her, the emperor orders the Duke to personally care for her until she comes of age, and then promptly execute her on her 18th birthday.
Her powers are that of a golem master. One of the reasons everyone finds her so pitiable is that she presents a bag of rocks as "her only friend"; the rocks are actually a golem that she can talk to.
The Duke's territory includes a large castle that was built using golem architecture, and thus has spirits that she can talk to. This includes a tiny maid, the "inner wall" and a gruff soldier, the "outer wall".
 

Heh, princesses with golems and asking to build a snowman...
